# Buttons inside of a Pop Over Controller on the iPad

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, ipad

I am attempting to create a popover similar to this in an iPad app.

[image]

Does anybody know if there is a built in way to do this? Is it a UISegmentedControl inside of a UIPopoverController?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it's *not* a segmented control inside a pop over controller. It's a menu controller.

You can get the shared menu controller, then edits its [`menuItems` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIMenuController/menuItems), and show it.

Answer (score 2):

a UIPoveroverController can contain any view controller in it....so if u have a ViewController that has a view that is a UISegmentedControl or whatever you need i dont see why it wouldnt work...Though as the poster above me pointed out, you can just use a UIMenuController..

Daniel