# Are there examples of how to use UIPopoverController on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I've seen some demos where UIPopoverController is used and would like to use it in my apps.

So does anyone have any good tutorials that you could link me?

Is it possible to use it in relation to UISegmentedControl where different popover windows are summoned when different segments are selected as a type of a switch view function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Jacob.  I've edited your questions to include appropriate tags for the platform you're asking about (iOS).  This will help you attract the attention of the right people here.  Also, I've removed the Xcode tag because that really should only be used when asking about the Xcode IDE itself.

Comment: In regards to this question some of the resources at this question might help you out: [Where can I find iPad Sample Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276513/where-can-i-find-ipad-sample-code)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are some tutorials:

- [iPad for iPhone Developers 101: UIPopoverController Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial)
- [[iPad App Video] iPad App Tutorial – UIPopoverController](http://ulapp.us/ipad-app-video-ipad-app-tutorial-uipopovercontroller/)

Segmented Popover:

- [Using a UISegmentedControl in the footer of UIPopoverController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284111/using-a-uisegmentedcontrol-in-the-footer-of-uipopovercontroller)
- [Buttons inside of a Pop Over Controller on the iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632436/buttons-inside-of-a-pop-over-controller-on-the-ipad), no UISegmentUISegmentedControl used but looks like one

Answer (score 0):

1. For popover in iPad we can use ActionSheetStringPicker, and for implementing it in your project you need to import ActionSheetStringPicker into your controller.
   like - #imaport "ActionSheetStringPicker.h"
2. After importing this you have to create an array which has only string type value.

e.g.

```
   NSArray *sourceArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Take Photo",@"Choose Photo", nil];
```

3. And last you have to implement below method.

   ```
   [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Any title"
                                               rows:sourceArray
                                   initialSelection:yourInitialSelectionIntValue
                                          doneBlock:^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker, NSInteger selectedIndex, id selectedValue) {

                                          NSLog(@" Index : %ld, value : %@",
                                                (long)selectedIndex, selectedValue);
                                          if ([selectedValue isEqualToString:@"Choose Photo"]) {

                                              // open photo lib
                                              [self youerMethdeOpenPhotoLib];

                                          }
                                          else
                                          {
                                              // open Camera
                                              [self yourMethodOpenCamera];
                                          }



                                      }
                                    cancelBlock:^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker) {
                                        NSLog(@"Select photo Cancel");

                                    }origin:YourTapButtonObject];
   ```