# How to add UIView in UIPopoverViewController?

Tags: ipad

How to add the UIView into UIPopoverViewController

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-(void) buttonAction:(id)sender {
    //build our custom popover view

       UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc]

                      init];

       UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc]

                      initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300)];

       popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

       popoverContent.view = popoverView;


    //resize the popover view shown
    //in the current view to the view's size

       popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover =

                      CGSizeMake(200, 300);


    //create a popover controller

       self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]

                   initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];


    //present the popover view non-modal with a
    //refrence to the button pressed within the current view
    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popoverButton.frame

                   inView:self.view

                   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny

                   animated:YES];


    //release the popover content
    [popoverView release];
    [popoverContent release];
    }

This will add the view to your UIPopoverViewController
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the following link below to get some idea as to how to do this

[Are there examples of how to use UIPopoverController on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744434/are-there-examples-of-how-to-use-uipopovercontroller-on-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Code:

```
if (mycontroller == nil) {
            MyController * viewController = [[MyController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ControllerView" bundle:nil];



            mycontroller = viewController;
            PopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.mycontroller];    
            PopoverController.delegate = self;
    }

 [PopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(260, 120, 10, 10) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```