# How to do UIView appear when click button like following picture?

Tags: ios

I want to appear another view in MainView when i clicked button like following picture.

Is there any tutorials or guides?

[image]

Comment: This is an `UIPopoverView`. Tutorial here: http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/using-popoverview-ipad-app-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744434/are-there-examples-of-how-to-use-uipopovercontroller-on-ios) for popOvers in iPad and use [this link](https://github.com/PaulSolt/WEPopover) for popOver in iPhone / iPod.

Answer (score 1):

That is called `UIPopoverController`. You should take a look at this [this](http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html). Everything very well explained.